# Quill Editor with math formula adding feature in Angular

Tags: angular, math, editor, formula, quill

I have Implemented a quill editor in angular. It can style the text message, Add images and video links, etc which works well now. As per requirement I may want to add mathematical formulas like this along with the above features. Can anyone please suggest to me an editor for performing this action in angular?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the Tinymce editor and then integrated it with Wiris.   Now the issue is resolved.

Comment: Could you show us an example/tutorial on how you achieved it?